# What is the CSS Component for the border in the Multi-level Navigation Menu component?

Tags: community, css

I'm looking to change the white border seen in this snip.
This is the dropdown that appears when selecting a Menu Item in the Multi-Level Navigation Menu.

[image: Multi-Level Navigation Menu]

EDIT:  Additional Information

```
ul[community_navigation-multiLevelNavigationList_multiLevelNavigationList] {
border: 1px solid #DC143C;
z-index: 500;
background: var(--lwc-brandNavigationBackgroundColor,#fff);
box-shadow: 0 2px 7px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16);
```

found this by inspecting, and I can manually edit the border and see it change... but I can't get it to stick and apply in the CSS Override.

specifically I tried this, as well as slight variations of spacing

```
.slds-m-vertical_medium .slds-m-horizontal_x-small .slds-is-absolute .slds-nubbin_top-left{
border: 1px solid #dc143c;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
.slds-dropdown.slds-dropdown--center.slds-nubbin--top {
    border-color: red;
}
```